# [SVN]: Is it possible to create a repository in a remote location?

Tags: svn

I want to create a Subversion repository in my hosted site web space. Is it possible and recommended to do this?  If yes, what are the steps involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion supports repository access via HTTP(S), but it requires that Apache be configured properly for it (namely, it requires the mod_dav and mod_dav_svn modules to be loaded, the repostiory root to be configured in httpd.conf, authentication to be configured properly, etc. -- see [the Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) for the nitty-gritty).

You'll need to check with your hosting provider to see if they support this and find out how to set it up with the particular tools/level of access that they give you.